# clear all controls inside tab using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a tabcontainer which contains 5 tabs. I want to clear all data inside each of the controls of tab1 using Jquery what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "controls" are we talking about form elements? And by clear do you mean "empty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will remove all content from elements matched with the given selector:

`$("<selector here>").html("");`

**Edit**

To remove data inside input elements:

`$("<selector here> input").val("");`

If `tabl` is a class, then use `.tabl` as the selector. If it is an id, use `#tabl`.

Comment: thanks. but i want to clear data inside each of the controls & not the controls

Answer (score 1):

By 'clear' do you mean empty their data, or to empty the tab completely?

Assuming your tab has an id of 'tab1':

```
$("#tabl>*").val(""); //clear all of the data 
$("#tabl>*").html(""); //empty the content completely
```